# How can i export my project as application

Tags: netbeans, export

Im finished my program from netbeans. I want to export my project as a application.

Thank you for answer

Comment: I am no Java programmer myself, but isn't a .jar file created every time you build the project?

Comment: Yes when i do clean and build, create a .jar file in dist folder